# How to get the server time in the MEAN stack ? (MongoDB, Express, Angular, Node)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

**CODE:**

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var article = new Article(req.body);
  article.user = req.user;

  console.log("1) LAST: "+article.user.last.getTime());
  console.log("Date.now() "+Date.now());

  if (article.user.last != null && article.user.last != undefined) {
      console.log("1");
      console.log("DATE: "+(Date.now() - article.user.last));
      if ((Date.now() - article.user.last.getTime() > 1000 * 60 * 60)) {
            article.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return res.status(422).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                  });
                } else {
                    res.json(article);

                    if (article.user) {
                        article.user.last = Date.now();
                        console.log("2) LAST: "+article.user.last.getTime());
                    } else {
                        res.status(401).send({
                          message: 'User is not signed in'
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
      }
      else {
          return res.status(422).send({
            message: "You need to wait 1 hour between Article creations or if you just created an account."
          });
      }
  }
  else {
      console.log("2");
      article.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(422).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
          });
        } else {
          res.json(article);

            if (article.user) {
                article.user.last = Date.now();
                console.log("3) LAST: "+article.user.last.getTime());
            } else {
                res.status(401).send({
                  message: 'User is not signed in'
                });
            }
        }
    });
  }
};
```

---

**SITUATION:**

Instead of using `Date.now()`, I would like to use the server time.

My anti-spam timer prevents a user from posting more than once every hour.

It works fine except for one thing: if I use Date.now(), I am able to bypass the timer by simply advancing my local clock by 1 hour.

Comment: `Date.now()` executed on the server is the **server** time. PS: From your code, this has nothing to do with angular nor mongodb.

Comment: @qqilihq The code you see above is my anti-spam timer. You need to wait 1 hour between posts. If Date.now() executed on the server IS the sever time, then why was I able to just advance my local clock by 1 hour to bypass the timer ?

Comment: @Coder1000 - Because you're testing locally. Your machine time is the server time.

Comment: @tymeJV Mind Blown :O

Comment: @tymeJV Write an answer so I can accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're testing locally - your machine is the server - so your test of setting your local machine ahead 1 hour wasn't really a valid test, as it also set the server time ahead an hour.

`Date.now()` is the correct way to get the time, btw. I'd also like to say to remember to use UTC when you're working with times like this.

Comment: Great ! I thought Date.now() was always taking the time of the client. TIL :D Thx!

Comment: Why UTC ? (I just used the default Date.now(), do I need to make a change ?)

Comment: UTC is how dates should be stored, in case your ever going to do more advanced things regarding timezones. `Date.now()` will work fine - unless your server unexpectedly switches timezones, then it could have issues. Always a fun read: http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html

Comment: Thx ! Will take a look at it :) (Also, you forgot to ping me, luckily I checked back here :D)

Comment: Ok, I read it. This is a setting I will just have to configure on my Server (VMs on Google Cloud Compute Engine), or is it something I have to set in my code ?

Comment: After a quick google search, it seems it should be done at the application level, not the server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29079052/jelastic-how-to-change-server-date-and-time-to-utc

Comment: Ok I found this: `$ export TZ="Europe/Amsterdam"; gulp myTask`here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083410/how-can-i-set-the-default-timezone-in-node-js   So I suppose that for UTC I should just do `$ export TZ="UTC"; gulp myTask` ?

Comment: @Coder1000 -- I would honestly just use `momentjs` on your node server, then just do `moment` methods: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873200/momentjs-getting-javascript-date-in-utc (this is the way I've done it with node in the past, I can't speak much to the gulp stuff)

Comment: Hello, would you know what causes this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102929/gigantic-time-lapse-between-two-date-now?noredirect=1#comment71376054_42102929

Answer (score -1):

Use $currentDate

See docs here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/

Comment: Does not work. I tried replacing `Date.now()` with `$currentDate` . "$currentDate is undefined". What have I done wrong ?

Comment: Thats not the way. Please read the docs. Since you have not written your full query in the question am unable to mention how to use $currentDate in your query.