# Gigantic time lapse between two Date.now()

Tags: javascript, date

**SITUATION:**

I have created a spam time-limit of 1 hour.

When a user posts, the current time `Date.now()` is saved in `user.last`.

When he posts again, I get the current time with `Date.now()` and compare it to `user.last`.

---

**PROBLEM:**

The problem is the following:

I post twice in about 1 minute.

The difference of time between the two posts is greater than 1 HOUR according to my the console output of my code.

---

**QUESTION:**

What have I done wrong ? I did set the env TZ to UTC.

---

**CODE:**

```
exports.create = function (req, res) {
  var article = new Article(req.body);
  article.user = req.user;

  console.log("LAST: "+article.user.last.getTime());
  console.log("Date.now(): "+Date.now());

  if (article.user.last.getTime() != null && article.user.last.getTime() != undefined) {
      console.log("DATE DIFFERENCE: "+(Date.now() - article.user.last));
      if ((Date.now() - article.user.last > 1000 * 60 * 60)) {
            article.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return res.status(422).send({
                    message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                  });
                } else {
                    res.json(article);

                    if (article.user) {
                        article.user.last = Date.now();
                        console.log("NEW LAST: "+article.user.last.getTime());
                    } else {
                        res.status(401).send({
                          message: 'User is not signed in'
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
      }
      else {
          return res.status(422).send({
            message: "You need to wait 1 hour between Article creations or if you just created an account."
          });
      }
  }
  else {
      console.log("2");
      article.save(function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return res.status(422).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
          });
        } else {
          res.json(article);

            if (article.user) {
                article.user.last = Date.now();
                console.log("3) LAST: "+article.user.last.getTime());
            } else {
                res.status(401).send({
                  message: 'User is not signed in'
                });
            }
        }
    });
  }
};
```

---

**CONSOLE:**

```
LAST: 1486438249652
Date.now(): 1486515834377
DATE DIFFERENCE: 77584725
NEW LAST: 1486515834394
```

---

**EDIT:**

User model

```
/**
 * User Schema
 */
var UserSchema = new Schema({

  //SOME CODE

  last: {
    type: Date
  },

  //SOME CODE

});
```

Comment: If you `console.log(article.user.last)` what do you get?

Comment: @jonmrich For example: `Tue Feb 07 2017 03:30:49 GMT+0000 (UTC)`

Comment: Then how does this `console.log("DATE DIFFERENCE: "+(Date.now() - article.user.last));` give you a number?

Comment: @jonmrich It's the result you currently see in my question.

Comment: Which of the values is correct? "LAST" or `Date.now()`

Comment: @jonmrich What do you mean by "correct" ?

Comment: The code you have looks like it's working perfectly fine. The difference between the last post and now is 21 hours so the code executes perfectly, which is why you get "NEW LAST" to output. If this isn't right, then the last post time (`article.user.last`) isn't accurate.

Comment: @jonmrich My post does not execute fine at all ! The post should not be allowed to be  saved since I explained in my questions that I want to prevent spam by setting a 1 hour limit which I have done. Problem is that I posted twice in 1 minute and the difference -as you just calculated- is 21 hours. The post is allowed after 1 minute when it shouldn't because the value comparison outputs 21 hours when it should output (less than) 1 minute.

Comment: @jonmrich  "If this isn't right, then the last post time `(article.user.last)` isn't accurate." This is the whole point of my question.

Comment: Does the 2nd request start after the 1st request has finished (and the data written to the DB)?

Comment: @SeánHayes What is the "2nd request" for you ?

Comment: You said you posted twice in one minute. You want the first to succeed and the 2nd to error out, right? Does the 2nd one start only after the first one has completed?

Comment: @SeánHayes Yes.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here. `article.user.last = Date.now()` sets article.user.last to a Number, not a Date. But the next line calls `article.user.last.getTime()` which will throw an error in any JS runtime. How is NEW LAST ever logged?

Comment: Could you post the console output for both requests together?

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan Touché Sir. The user.last is a Date in the User Model (MEAN app). Let me add the model to my question.

Comment: Okay, so... are you saying you're using a setter or a Proxy to trap the integer assignment, to avoid throwing the error?

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan No, actually I am using getTime() only to be able to compare the values in milliseconds in my console.logs. It serves no real use in the code. Should I set last's type to a Number ?

Comment: Your code already sets it to a Number:  

    if (article.user) {
                        article.user.last = Date.now();
                        console.log("NEW LAST: "+article.user.last.getTime());
                    }

Date.now() returns a number. So, article.user.last is a number after you the above code runs; you cannot call .getTime() on a number.

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan Yes, but then I save it to my model that converts it to a Date to store it. My theory is that that somehow messes up the time zone and creates the huge time lapse I see. But I am not sure.

Comment: Oh I see, it's a mongoose schema. What time zone are you in? (How far from UTC?)

Comment: @jeff_mcmahan In my question: " I did set the env TZ to UTC." So normally all dates are UTC 00:00 I checked and the dates are indeed all UTC normally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135135/discussion-between-jeff-mcmahan-and-coder1000).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the user record isn't actually being saved. Your code saves the Article, and then *sets* the user's `.last` property, but at no point is the Mongoose model for the user being saved (`article.user.save()`).

That means `.last` remains whatever it was when it was first created, and so the logged date difference will increase monotonically.

Here's the important bit:

```
article.save(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    res.status(422).send({message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)});
  } else {
    if (article.user) {
      article.user.last = Date.now();
      article.user.save(function (err) {
        if (err) res.status(500).send({message: 'Database error'});
        else res.json(article);
      }
    } else {
      res.status(401).send({message: 'User is not signed in'});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think *increase monotonically* is an oxymoron.

Comment: @RobG I don't think so :D "monotonically" means: `(of a function or quantity) varying in such a way that it either never decreases or never increases.` "increase monotonically" means that it always increases and never decreases. This is actually a term often used in maths (Analysis) classes since there are quite  a lot of monotonically increasing functions :D

Comment: @RobG Wolfram Alpha: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotoneIncreasing.html

Comment: @Coder1000—that's the point, the term is incorrectly applied. *Monotonic* should mean never changing, or having only one value, hence the contradiction of *monotonically increasing*. There is already a term for only ever moving in one direction (up or down): *unidirectional*. But I don't get to tell mathematicians how to name their concepts. :-(

Comment: @RobG Oh ! Well :-)